# Newer style of faucet handle removal with no screw and hole

Tags: plumbing

I need to repair the dripping faucet, but have no idea how to remove the handle, as it shows on the pic, there is no screw or tap or hole on it, any suggestions? or seen this type?  It seems there is only one way to do it by pulling it up?[image]

I thought removing the handle is the hard part, I was wrong, now I can't take the cartridge out, as it shows on the pic, the cartridge seated too deep, and my wrench can't have a good grab, is there a special tool for this kind of cartridge?[image]

Comment: Try carefully prying the handle up with a small screwdriver in the  crack  between the handle and the base.  I've had a few that popped off by doing this.

Comment: ^^, but also check for a grub screw (set screw) in the back...